# Turn off auto sleep while streaming to apple tv on iPad

Tags: ipad, appletv

I am streaming YouTube to my appleTv and after a few minutes my iPad goes to sleep. I have tried using Mobile Safari to stream and the YouTube app from the iOS app store.

Can the auto sleep be turned off while streaming?

If so, is it also possible to preserve 2 minute sleep otherwise?

Comment: Are you using Safari or YouTube app or some other browser to display youtube content on the Apple TV?

Comment: I was playing with the YouTube app.

Comment: But I also checked it with the safari and the issue is no more an issue with safari...